# Sphinx or MySQL Full-text for searching through sub-1000 data entries?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, sphinx

Should I use Sphinx or MySQL full-text for searching through no more than 1000 database entires in different tables?

Later on I plan to display the entries that match the search keywords on a map as points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All depends on your level of use and need.  I would suggest you start with MySQL full-text searching - its easier to implement and will get you to production faster.  You can always plan to upgrade later as your demands dictate.

Comment: Can MySQL search with multiple keywords provided? Let's say I enter `auto parts` into seach box. It needs to be able to search through varchar(single text value), non-varchar(non-alpha) and text(description, etc.) columns.

Comment: Yes. Just make sure you create the full text index against all the columns you want to be able to serach http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html